NJ Employer health insurance offerings
How do you find out what health insurance plans are offered by employers in NJ to their employees?  Is there a website I can look at? Thankyou.

You'd probably ask them?

For what purpose?  Companies publish the list of plan options to employees during open enrollment which is usually at the end of the calendar year but differs for different companies.  Particularly for big companies, though, those plans are often bespoke offerings.  Health insurers publish the list of plans they offer.  Individual plans would normally be offered on the state insurance exchange.

In my very limited experience, the employer health insurance offerings may not be finalized until shortly before the open enrollment period starts. I wouldn't expect to see details before October.


How do you find out what health insurance plans are offered by
employers in NJ to their employees? Is there a website I can look at?

For current employees the insurance options and costs are provided during open season, or when an employee needs to add insurance after a qualified life event. This information should be on the employee accessible intra-net or through the HR POC.
A company should also provide their insurance offerings info with an offer letter.  They generally won't provide the exact details to somebody before the offer stage. If you have an offer letter but no insurance details, then ask the company for them.
Unless the state government requires the employer to provide these details there will not be an official website to provide this information to non-employees. There can be websites that provide company ratings that claim they have some of these details, but they can't guarantee their estimates are correct.
The costs and options can vary within a state. The medical providers network costs for the part of New Jersey near New York city may be different than the network near Philadelphia or Atlantic City.
Not all insurance companies are everywhere. In addition the costs and options will depend on the size of the company. Policies from employers may be completely different from those listed on the insurance exchange.
